# Creating your own cascade(.xml) file

Tags: opencv, cascade-classifier

I have started to study object detection with Python-OpenCV. I want to create my own cascade files. Is there any software/technology that will do it instead of me? For example, I can just give the positive and the negative images and then it gives me a cascade.xml file as output to train.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV provide these tools:

https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html

https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/db/d28/tutorial_cascade_classifier.html

> Working with a boosted cascade of weak classifiers includes two major stages: the training and the detection stage. The detection stage using either HAAR or LBP based models, is described in the object detection tutorial. This documentation gives an overview of the functionality needed to train your own boosted cascade of weak classifiers. The current guide will walk through all the different stages: collecting training data, preparation of the training data and executing the actual model training.
>
> To support this tutorial, several official OpenCV applications will be
>   used: opencv_createsamples, opencv_annotation, opencv_traincascade and
>   opencv_visualisation.